# Send data between two remote servers with popen, fgets and ssh

Tags: php, ssh, pipe, stdin, popen

I try to communicate two machines by ssh and pipe to get a message from one to another. 
The second reads the message form the first machine with sdtin and writing in text file.

I have a machine where I have this program but it's doesn't work...

```
$message = "Hello Boy";
$action = ('ssh root@machineTwo script.php'); 
$handle = popen($action, 'w');

if($handle){
   echo $message;
   pclose($handle);
}
```

On the other machine, machineTwo i have :

```
 $filename = "test.txt";    
     if(!$fd = fopen($filename, "w");
     echo "error";
        }
     else {
            $action = fgets(STDIN);
            fwrite($fd, $action);
    /*On ferme le fichier*/
    fclose($fd);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is working :

**MACHINE ONE**

I send a message to the *MACHINE TWO* after being connected to *MACHINE TWO* with ssh. I use `popen` and `fwrite`

```
//MACHINE ONE
$message = "Hello Boy";
$action = ('ssh root@machineTwo script.php');  //conection by ssh-rsa
$handle = popen($action, 'w'); //pipe open between machineOne & two

if($handle){
   fwrite($handle, $message); //write in machineTwo
   pclose($handle);
}
```

**MACHINE TWO**

I open a file with `fopen` and get the message of *MACHINE ONE* with *fgets(STDIN);*. I write the message in the file opened.

```
//MACHINETWO
$filename = "test.txt";    
if(!$fd = fopen($filename, "w");
    echo "error";
}

else
{   
    $message = fgets(STDIN);
    fwrite($fd, $message); //text.txt have now Hello World !
    /*we close the file*/
    fclose($fd);    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simplest way to do that (uses [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)):

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('php script.php');
?>
```

With an RSA private key:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('privatekey'));
if (!$ssh->login('username', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('php script.php');
?>
```

If script.php listens on stdin you could maybe do [read() / write()](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#interactive) or use [enablePTY()](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/pull/71)

Answer (score -1):

Popen is mostly used to have two local program communicate using a "pipeline file".

To achieve what you want, you should try the SSH2 PHP library (an interesting link http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/24/make-ssh-connections-with-php/ )

In your case you would do something like that for your php script on machineOne:

```
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
if (!($con = ssh2_connect("machineTwo", 22))) {
    echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
} else {
    if (!ssh2_auth_password($con, "root", "yourpass")) {
        echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
    } else {
        echo "okay: logged in...\n";

         if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "php script.php"))) { //execute php script on machineTwo
                echo "fail executing command\n";
            } else {
                // collect returning data from command
                stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                $data = "";
                while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
                    $data .= $buf;
                }
                fclose($stream);
                echo $data; //text returned by your script.php
            }
    }
}
```

I assume you have a good reason to do this, but why use PHP ?